# How to use "come true" in a such sentence

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering to use a sentence like:

> I am about to make one of my childhood dream come true.

Is it a best practice?

Comment: This looks correct, but what exactly are you looking for help on? What verb tenses to use? The structure of the sentence? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Actually I want the sentence exactly the same as I wrote up. I just couldn't be sure whether it is a correct usage or not. I planned the sentence to use inside a job interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dream" should be "dreams", but other than that, your sentence is correct. "Come true" is used properly here.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct but I would say "one of my childhood **dreams** come true" if I had more than one dream. If only one, then "I'm about to make my childhood **dream** come true"